# How to get the previous month last day with bind data

Tags: php

How i will get the previous month last date using php

this is my bind data

`$getDate = "2017-04-19"`

I'm trying to get the last month day using php and I'm having a hard time finding the answer.

the result i want to get is

```
$lastMonthDay= "2017-03-31"
```

Comment: yes this question is already exists..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime(); // 2017-04-19
$date->modify("last day of previous month");
echo $newdate = $date->format("Y-m-d");  // its Print Date

echo date('D', strtotime($newdate ));   // its Print Day

?>
```

**Demo :** https://eval.in/824466

Comment: thank you sr for your reply . this is what i`m looking for.. thanks :D your my savior

Comment: any time bro :) ... Happy to help :)

Comment: its such a big help for a beginner like me T_T i have a lot of question but i`m having a hard time explain it well in english ..  hahaha

Comment: lol... :D ... no problem .. and why uncheck the ans ?? after check ?

Comment: ops sory wrong click heheh .

Comment: it's okzz but after you check the right you unchecked the ans so i ask you !! nothing else..

Answer (score 2):

You could use DateTime with modify:

```
$d = new DateTime('2017-04-19');
$d->modify('last day of previous month');

$lastMonthDay = $d->format('Y-m-d');
```

Live example: https://3v4l.org/KEBAH

Comment: i just get back to work after i sleep thank you sr for your response it such a big help for me ..

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you want the last day of the previous month.

This should work: `$lastMonthDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of previous month'));`

Comment: but with a bind data..
$getDate = "2017-04-19"
i have a given date and i want to get last day of the previous  month

Comment: @ElliJoshuaRey, Checkout my answer and let me know is it okay for you or not?

Comment: sory i just get back to work .. 
no sr i need the command that will get the previous month last day with a bind data.. but they already got what exact command i needed.. thank you sr for your response 
`$date_created = '2017-04-19'`
`$date = new DateTime($date_created);`
`$date->modify("last day of previous month");
 $newdate = $date->format("Y-m-d");`

this is the command i  use with a bind data

Answer (score 1):

Last day of previous month:

Using general way-

```
$getDate = "2017-04-19";
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($getDate.' -1 month'));
echo $date = date('Y-m-t', strtotime($date)); //2017-03-31
```

Using Object Oriented-

```
$date = new DateTime($getDate);
$date->modify('last day of previous month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); //2017-03-31
```

Comment: This answer is already given 2 times

Comment: Yes, After posting i saw that

Comment: its print the date only .. `2017-03-31`

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar, The user want to get this answer. Look: `$lastMonthDay= "2017-03-31"`

Comment: @Daniel, I update my answer with both ways.

Comment: @FrayneKonok ... okzz But  you have to read the Comments of `Ryan Hipkiss`  ANS .. Just Check it.

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar, What's the problem with that comment?

Comment: @FrayneKonok He wants to get last `day` of the `previous month`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147915/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-rishikesh-kumar).

Comment: thank you guys for helping me.